# Qual Cipher Suite do Apache2 é compatível com Chrome 49 no Windows XP?

Tags: apache, ssl

Preciso que um site seja acessível no Windows XP usando HTTPS, porém o que obtenho são erros de handshake.

Minhas configurações do Apache2 estão da seguinte forma.

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLCompression Off
[... caminhos dos certificados ...]
```

O site funciona corretamente em sistemas mais novos, porém não no Windows XP.

No site SSLLabs recebo a mensagem:

> Chrome 49 / XP SP3    Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure

A URL do teste está acessível neste link: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.tecdicas.com&s=104.28.26.14&latest

Meu site utiliza o Cloudflare Full Strict SSL, e em sua configuração, não desativei os legacy browsers.

No SO em Inglês encontrei a informação de que o sistema não suporta algorítimos mais novos, porém preciso saber qual é suportado para manter o acesso aos sistemas usando Chrome no Windows XP.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922231/why-cant-windows-xp-handle-newer-ssl-certificate-versions

**Como posso deixar o site acessível para o Chrome no Windows XP? Qual cipher suite posso acrescentar para ser acessível ao menos no Chrome?**

Comment: Você está usando o plano pago ou gratuito, do CloudFlare? Se for o primeiro caso, esse é o motivo. Está usando o certificado padrão do CloudFlare ou um customizado (usando o plano Business)?

Comment: Estou utilizando o plano gratuito, porém removi o Cloudflare e refiz os testes e obtive o mesmo problema. Quando removi a linha de Cipher Suites do Apache2 funcionou, porém o SSL labs passou a indicar que utilizava uma criptografia fraca. Então eu queria manter essa linha, e permitir ao menos 1 cipher suite compatível com XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Windows XP suporta nativamente somente protocolos quebrados (ou fracos, se quiser ser otimista), para começar ele apenas oferece suporte para SSLv2, SSLv3 e TLS 1.0, ou seja TLS 1.1 e 1.2 não são suportados.

As listas de Cipher Suite disponíveis nativamente no Windows XP são:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA
TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
```

Ele apenas suporta coisas que já são consideradas não recomendadas, como RC4, DES e 3DES. Claro, SHA-1 e MD5, que nem precisa comentar. O Chrome não suporta mais SHA-1 e MD5 nas versões mais recentes, Chrome 54 e posteriores, salvo engano.

Para comparação, o Windows 10 suporta AES-GCM, SHA384, SHA256, além de suportar criptografia de curva elíptica, permitindo usar ECDHE e ECDSA.

---

O plano básico/gratuito do CloudFlare usa certificado de curva elíptica, logo não suportado pelo Windows XP. Eles mesmos dizem isso:

> Our SSL certificates on paid plans (Pro, Business and Enterprise) will work with all desktop browsers, so if you are worried about compatibility or have many users with old browsers upgrading to one of our paid plans is recommended

[Fonte](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203041594-What-browsers-work-with-Cloudflare-s-SSL-certificates-)

---

Este é um conjunto abaixo é compatível, **porém não é tão seguro**. Não existe "ser compatível com Windows XP" e ao mesmo tempo "ser seguro", basta ver o teste usando o google.com, ele mesmos usam `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` (compatível com XP) e o SSL Labs informa "WEAK".

O `RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` é compatível com o Windows XP, porém é fraco, para usa-lo defina em `EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA`:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!MD5
```

Acredito que seja suficiente.

Se quiser um mais abrangente utilize:

```
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
```

Se quiser algo realmente seguro esqueça o Windows XP e o Windows Vista. Simplesmente somente suporte para TLS 1.2 (e o TLS 1.3). Apenas permita usar ECDHE como forma de troca e suporte apenas AES-GCM e CHACHA20-POLY1305:

```
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

Isso irá suportar AES128-GCM, AES256-GCM e o CHACHA20-POLY1305. O motivo da repetição é que você pode usar ECC ou RSA, o que vai definir o uso de ECDSA ou RSA como assinatura.

Um outro ponto importante é performance, o `ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305` acredito que seja o mais rápido.

Comment: Resolveu o meu problema sem o Cloudflare. Com o Cloudflare você tem razão sobre eles não suportarem. Muito obrigado pela sua resposta.